# How to eliminate duplicates with a left join and a case statement?

Tags: sql, db2

Here is a small sample of the problem code:

```
SELECT
REFNUMBER

,CASE WHEN DESC = 'ABCD' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END AS "DOESN'T WORK"

LEFT OUTER JOIN X.ZWNY Z
ON A.REFNUMBER = Z.REFNUMBER
```

Pretty basic stuff.  However, there are instances where "ABCD" can occur multiple times for each REFNUMBER in table X.ZWNY and there aren't any other unique identifiers to limit the results.  Is there a way to put something like DISTINCT or anything similar to make it return only the first occurrence of "ABCD"?  I apologize if I have overlooked something simple, but I can't seem to get there.

Comment: what is `A` in your query?

Comment: your query is missing the FROM clause

Comment: I apologize for the structure, but I only provided a very small sample of my query to avoid having to scrub sensitive info from 100+ lines of code.  I provided just enough to get an idea of the problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `left join`.  Use `exists`:

```
select refnumber,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from X.ZWNY Z
                          where A.REFNUMBER = Z.REFNUMBER and DESC = 'ABCD'
                         )
             then 'Y' else ''
        end) as BetterColumnName
from A;
```

Note:  `DESC` is also a bad column name because it is a SQL reserved word (used for `order by`).

Comment: That worked like an absolute charm.  Thank you very much.  Yeah, I have had issues with the DESC column name before.  I have zero control over the structure of the tables unfortunately :(

Comment: You might try quotes: `"DESC"`